How to install guest additions on CentOS 9 stream in VirtualBox?
Is there any YouTube/steps of how to install Guest Additions on a fresh install of CentOS 9 Stream in Oracle VirtualBox?
I succeeded for Oracle Linux, Rocky Linux 9, Ubuntu 24.04.1, but CentOS 9 is failing.
Commands I used
sudo yum update
sudo dnf update -y
sudo dnf install -y gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers make bzip2 perl elfutils-libelf-devel
sudo dnf install -y epel-release

I've uploaded file to my google drive here

Can you give us specifics on how it’s failing? Please [edit] your question to include the necessary information to submit an answer to your question

Welcome to Superuser. Requests that we recommend training or learning resources are off topic here. Ask the actual question you have, not "what training will answer my questoin". Also, telling us the names or giving us links to things you've tried doesn't help us. Instead, list the specific steps you took and the things you tried and the outcome. Please EDIT your post to improve, expand, and clarify it. Read the HELP section if you need further info on how to ask good questions and what is and is not allowed to ask.

@Ramhound - I've asked chat gpt and checked everywhere. I'm sure this is a bug or something. It can't be that complex

@aymanzone - ChatGPT is incapable of diagnosing a problem like this. Can you provide those specifics I asked for nearly a day ago?

hi @Ramhound thank you for follow up. I edit my reply and uploaded the full log file to my google drive - let me know if that is good and thank you

I assume you have tried “sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run”?

@Ramhound yes  have. I posted in the VirtualBox forum and it's basically a cat and mouse game between centosOS and VB Guest additions. I have to find the right versions between them

I have tested, and test build version 7.1.x revision 165591 worked fine now.

Thank you @ML85 for the info . I quit centos and I am using Rocky Linux 9. I may go back to it later
